# parameters in for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on this project for school. 
But I cannot figure out one problem.

I have 2 lines of boxed both colored, but I use a for loop and in the parameters don't work in the for loop. The lines have both different places and different length. So how could I use the parameters in the for loop? Just right so it would work everytime.

The code I have so far:

```
box('box', 3);
box('box2, 4);
function box(id,aantal){ 
   for(var i = 0; i < aantal.length; i++){
   var box = document.createElement("div");
       box.style.height = "175px";
       box.style.width= "175px";
       box.style.borderRadius = "5px";
       box.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";
       box.style.marginLeft ="25px";
       box.style.marginTop = "-160px";
       box.style.float = "left";
   document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
   }
}
```

Comment: box('box2, 4); you have a missing '

Answer (score 2):

`aantal` parameter is a number thus you should not use `aantal.length` but simply

```
for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
```

```js
box('box', 3);
box('box2', 4);

function box(id, aantal) {
  for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    box.style.height = "175px";
    box.style.width = "175px";
    box.style.borderRadius = "5px";
    box.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";
    box.style.marginLeft = "25px";
    box.style.float = "left";
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 box('box', 3);
 box('box2', 4);   
 function box(id,aantal){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
    var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.style.height = "175px";
        box.style.width= "175px";
        box.style.borderRadius = "5px";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";
        box.style.marginLeft ="25px";
        box.style.marginTop = "-160px";
        box.style.float = "left";
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the code below, what I can see is that in the second call to `box`,
you are not closing the string, which would cause a runtime error. The call should look like this: `box('box2', 4);`. What is also a problem is that you are expecting `aantal` to be an array, since you are accessing it's `length` property. However, you are passing integers as `aantal` to the function.

```
box('box', 3);
box('box2, 4);
function box(id, aantal){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < aantal.length; i++){
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.style.height = "175px";
        box.style.width= "175px";
        box.style.borderRadius = "5px";
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";
        box.style.marginLeft ="25px";
        box.style.marginTop = "-160px";
        box.style.float = "left";
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(box);
    }
}
```

If the function should create a number of boxes, then your loop should look more like `for(var i = 0; i < aantal; i++)`, since aantal is a number itself. Such a loop would then create the number of boxes that you passed in as the second argument.